# How to stop Shiny Leaflet map from recentering each time a control widget is changed

Tags: r, shiny, leaflet

I am making a Shiny Leaflet map that shows a set of rivers with water quality data by month.  Following is my server code for rendering the leaflet.  I would like to change it so that the map is not redrawn and recentered every time the user changes the month control widget.  I can't figure out how to do this.  I have tried putting the setView statement inside an if() clause using a global variable that tracks whether this is the first run, but I get errors.  I have tried removing the setView statement completely, but the map still redraws to the default bounds of the rivers and data.

```
ui <- fluidPage(
  sidebarLayout(
    sidebarPanel(
      sliderInput(inputId = "month",
        label = "Month (March-November)",
        min = 3, max = 11,
        step = 1, ticks = FALSE,
        value = 9)
    )
    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput("map", width = "100%", height = 480)
    )
  )
)

server <- function(input, output){       
    output$map <- renderLeaflet({
        map <- leaflet(DFA()) %>% addProviderTiles(providers$Esri.WorldGrayCanvas) %>%
          setView(-71.46, 42.42, zoom = 10) %>%
          addPolylines(data = majStrm, color = "blue",
                       weight = 2, smoothFactor = 1) %>%
          addCircleMarkers(lng = ~Lon, lat = ~Lat,
                           fillColor = ~pal(DFA()[,7]), 
                           fillOpacity = 0.9,
                           radius = 6, 
                           stroke = TRUE, weight = 1, 
                           color = "black", opacity = 1)
        map
      })
}
```

Comment: Where are you using the input "inputId"?

Comment: Sorry.  I left that section out.  I am using it to update DFA().

Answer (score 1):

It's a normal behavior. `renderLeaflet` builds a new map each time it is triggered by an embedded reactive value. What you have to do is to use the `leafletProxy` function.

Use a simple `observer` to draw the initial map by using `leaflet()` then use an `observeEvent` triggered by `DFA()` and using `leafletProxy("map")` in place of `leaflet()` to update the map instead of recreating it.

```
# create static part of map
output$map <- renderLeaflet({
  leaflet() %>%
    ... whatever to build base map ...
    ... without reactive part ...  
})

# handle the update of the static map with reactive part
observe({
  # update map
  leafletProxy("map", data=DFA()) %>%
     clearMarkers() %>%
     addCircleMarkers(...)
})
```

Comment: I agree. Use leafletProxy to update the map. But another approach is to keep track of the map scaling yourself and reapply it when you redraw the leaflet.

Comment: Right. But depending of the complexity of the map it's worth it

Comment: This solution helped a lot, but I couldn't get it to work as written.  My final solution that works is as follows

Comment: This solution helped a lot, but I couldn't get it to work as written.  My final solution that works is as follows:  I only use observe on the update map section.  The create map section starts with output$map <- renderLeaflet({map <- leaflet() %>%... The update map section starts with observe({leafletProxy("map", data=DFA())  %>%...  If you adjust the answer, I can mark it as correct.

Comment: Thanks for your observations. It was meant as quick hints to direct you to the answer before completing it for others.